# VueJS VeeValidate renders span even if there's a "slim"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I am using [VeeValidate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/) for my form validation.

This is my code:

```html
 <ValidationProvider :rules="rules" :name="name" v-slot="{ errors }" slim>
        <input
            :id="id"
            type="checkbox"
            :class="className"
            v-model="currentValue"
        >
        <div class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</div>
 </ValidationProvider>
```

According to their documentation [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-provider.html#rendering), we can implement a renderless mechanism by putting a `slim` attribute. That means it won't generate a `<span>` or a `<div>` that wraps the entire input and error element.

When I tried that, it still wraps the entire input and error element.

It outputs like this:

```html
<span>
  <input id="toc" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <div class="text-danger"></div>
</span>
```

I expect that it should just output like this according to their documentation:

```html
<input id="toc" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
```

I also noticed that if I removed this it works as expected:

```html
<div class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</div>
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-observer.html#forcing-renderless) explain this:

> Note that `slim` will take effect only when you have one child element in the slot as you cannot have multiple root nodes in a renderless component. Otherwise the tag will be rendered anyway.

Comment: i honestly do not know what's the meaning of that. Sorry.

Comment: The docs state that only one child element is allowed for the `slim` prop to work. Your `ValidationProvider` has two child elements (the `input` and the `div`), so the `span` wrapper is automatically applied. That's why removing the `div` (leaving just one element in the `ValidationProvider`) removes the `span` wrapper.